# Splitting a full name including title into separate fields

Tags: sql, string, split, db2

I'm trying to split a full name field into separate fields in a seemingly ancient version of DB2 so I can't use newer functions like reverse.

Example

FULL_NAME

Mr Elton John

Mr Keanu Reeves

I'd like to return

TITLE   FIRST   LAST

Mr  Elton   John

Mr  Keanu   Reeves

I'm frustratingly close, I've managed to get the last name with

```
RIGHT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME) - LOCATE( ' ',NAME, LOCATE(' ', NAME)+1)) AS last_name
```

But DB2 isn't really my thing so any help is massively appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know all the names have three components?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff is hinting at... you'll need to handle all the cases if you want clean data. Which means if you've got a `Mr. Hunter S. Thompson` or a `Sir Kermit the Frog` in there, you'll need to handle it. There are lots of potential exceptions.

Comment: I think theirs potential for the odd record to be missing a first name but I'll handle that on my import with an ifnull. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 supports [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAE4W_9.5.1/db2/rbafzscaregexp_substr.htm), so you should be able to do:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) as title,
       regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) as firstname,
       regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 3) as lastname
```

But if you don't have `reverse()`, you may not have this function either.

Comment: Answered that devastatingly quickly, worked as well. Thanks very much!